# How to get counts of sends/opens/clicks events from the FuelSDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, soap-api, fuel-sdk

I can use a GET on the objects SentEvent, OpenEvent, and ClickEvent, with a DateTime filter, to get all the email sends, email opens, and email clicks for a specified time period. Is there a way to get just a ​*count*​ of each of these events, instead of pulling all the actual events?

Of course, I can get all the actual events and then count them, but if an object or API call exists that returns the count directly instead of the actual event objects, presumably it is faster and performance is currently an issue.

Also, I DON'T want the counts of events associated with a particular object like an EmailSend or a TriggeredSendDefinition. I want the TOTAL across all sends, for the specified time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this particular aggregation of data doesn't exist in the platform.

My suggestion would be to create a set of [Query Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) to build this view of the activity.  Then you can simply retrieve this data via API ([DataExtensionObject](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionobject/)).

As you mentioned, the [SentEvent](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/sentevent/) does include some aggregate data that would be pretty simple to aggregate, but anything beyond that, you'll have to build.